# Error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' into header

Tags: angular, rest, api, http, cors

In my Angular application when I required a GET call from my API with a basic authentication I get this error in my JS console:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at '*********' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

The same call doesn't have any problem if I try with Postman. How can I fix?
This is my code:

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private postsURL = "********";

  getData(){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Length,X-Foo,X-Bar',
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('*****:*****')
      })
    };

    return this.http.get(this.postsURL, httpOptions); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CORS headers should be set in server-side. To solve your problem you can set a proxy.
Take a look at the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: @Xing doesn't matter if in Postman working properly and in my code I put the flag Access-Control-Allow-Origin into headers?

Comment: Postman is not bound by the same origin policy, so it does not require CORS support from the server.

Comment: CORS headers are response headers - set on the server. The reason Postman works is because - unlike a browser - it doesn’t prevent CORS requests...